# c# Use like command "field name" with space between field name (access database)

Tags: c#

first sry for my bad title

i have prblem for loading field name form access database because my field name in access table is="نام خانوادگی" 
so when i use this query :

```
DataView dvtell = dtTell.DefaultView;
       dvtell.RowFilter = "نام خانوادگی LIKE '%" + textBox6.Text + "%'";
```

return error because between نام and خانوداگی is a space .
but when i use query without 'space' // my code working good . 
any suggestion ? how can i use this 'نام خانوادگی' field name in my code ? 
i have 5 field name with space and i cant use it .

Comment: Put your field name within square brackets [.....] but it is better to change that name to not have spaces.

Comment: Wo0h . brackets working good .Tnx steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using square brackets, like this:

```
dvtell.RowFilter = "[نام خانوادگی] LIKE '%" + textBox6.Text + "%'";
```

Comment: @stackover if works please check for the correct answer.